# How to use 'select if' function with sequelize in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am developing a rest api in nodejs. I am using the sequelize library with
a postgresql database.

With sequelize in nodejs I want to get a temporary column to manage some values. I have two column `vip_start` and `vip_end`. These columns are `DataTypes.DATEONLY` format.

When I select all the columns, I want to compare two dates, and finally create a new column with the answer. If true then `1`, else `0`. And then I want to order the selected rows by `VIP_ANSWER (1 or 0)`.

In mysql it solves that like this:

```
( SELECT IF (CURDATE( ) >= DATE( vip_start ) AND CURDATE( ) <= DATE( vip_end ), 1, 0 ) ) as vip
```

How can I make it in sequelize? :

```
const datetime = new Date();
return Phones
    .findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'description',  'vip_start', 'vip_end','user_id' ],//I want to there new column like vip_answer [1,0] and order by this values
         where: {
             enabled: 1,
             vip_start: { $lte: datetime }, // in there i am stopped (((
         },
       })
    .then(phone => res.status(200).send(phone));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just add**

```
[ sequelize.literal('( SELECT IF (CURDATE( ) >= DATE( vip_start ) AND CURDATE( ) <= DATE( vip_end ), 1, 0 ) )'),'vip']
```

**To your attribute list :**

```
attributes: ['id', 'description',  'vip_start', 'vip_end','user_id' , [ sequelize.literal('( SELECT IF (CURDATE( ) >= DATE( vip_start ) AND CURDATE( ) <= DATE( vip_end ), 1, 0 ) )'),'vip'] ]
```

Comment: @Benfactor , then please create query in Postgres and then you can use that like above.

Comment: Please check : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I change syntax and it works. [sequelize.literal('( CASE WHEN (vip_start <= CURRENT_DATE) AND (vip_end >= CURRENT_DATE) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END )'), 'vip']

Comment: sequelize.literal this is a nice feature that I learn just now

Comment: Sorry i have little problem, I want to order rows by vip, it gives databaseError syntax near vip

Comment: @Benfactor, Yeah , Great that you made it , Happy Coding BTW :) , Yes coz you can't access such field in order by.